# Translate C++ code into R code for data generating purposes

Tags: c++, r, translate

I wish to create some data according to the following code for my master thesis but i am only familiar with R , some guidance on what the following code does or an implementation of it in R would be appreciated.

```
case 9: // generates a 20-dim affine space  in 100- dimensions
       dim=20;

       // allocate memory for the output
       plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(dim, num, mxREAL);
       data = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

       para=new double*[20];
       for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        para[i]=new double[long(num)];

       for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        for(j=0;j<num;j++)
         para[i][j]=5.0*uni()-2.5;

       vectors=new double*[20];
       for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        vectors[i]=new double[dim];

       for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
        {
          if(i==j)
           vectors[i][j]=1;
          else
           vectors[i][j]=0;//0.25*(uni()-0.125);
        }
         //vectors[i][j]=10*(uni()-0.5);

       //generate the figure
       for(i=0;i<num;i++)
       {
         for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
         {
           data[i*dim+j]=0;
           for(k=0;k<20;k++)
            data[i*dim+j]+=para[k][i]*vectors[k][j];
         }
       }
       mexPrintf("Generated %i data points of a 20-dimensional affine subspace in R^20\n",num);
       mexPrintf("The correct dimension of this submanifold is 20\n");

       for(i=0;i<20;i++)
        delete para[i];
       delete para;
       break;
```

`num` is the number of points i want to generate and `dim` the dimension so they are in essence my input.

I edited my post since i see that the whole code would be needed for a proper answer, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Rcpp` package? This runs C++ code directly from R. Especially if you have more C++ code, this may be worthwhile.

Comment: Sure i am familiar with the Rcpp package but in this case i want to translate this code into R code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one translation that maybe you can try

```
vectors <- matrix(nrow = 20,ncol = dim)
for (i in 1:20) {
    for (j in 1:dim) {
        vectors[i,j] <- ifelse(i==j,1,0)
    }
} 
for (i in 1:20) {
    for (j in 1:dim) {
        data[i*(dim-1+j)] <- 0
        for (k in 1:20) {
            data[i*(dim-1)+j] <- data[i*(dim-1)+j] + para[k,i]*vectors[k,j]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me for editing my original post but i felt like that providing the whole code would make it much easier for others to help me.

Comment: @SteliosKounis Sorry I don't know about `mxCreateDoubleMatrix`, `mxGetPr` and `mexPrintf`, thus no clue for their translation